# Building an App that works in Group & Professional Edition?

Tags: managed-package, app, isv, group-edition, professional-edition

What are the considerations when trying to build an AppExchange Application that works for Group or Professional Edition? I understand that there are a lot of Professional edition org and it would be great to be able to have them as customers too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Building for 'Group Edition' and 'Professional Edition' there are some things to keep in mind:

- Professional Edition doesn't support web service calls unless the org
  is API enabled (although this is possible it's not well documented)
- Permission sets are not available in in PE, and including them in a package can cause issues uninstalling a package from a PE org.
- Use of `@RemoteAction` calls aren't limited in the same way, so they're advisable for supporting PE.
- Some types of `Dashboards` aren't supported in GE and can limit the user from installing into their org.
- Sharing rules and `Profiles` are not supported in the same way in PE
- Some objects such as `Campaigns` are not included in these editions by default.

You should always attempt to install your app into a PE and GE edition org before releasing it to the AppExchange in order to confirm it's interoperability so that users coming in from the AppExchange don't encounter issues.

I'm giving a presentation at Dreamforce '12 that Includes notes on supporting and testing multiple editions. It's called `Team Development on the Force.com Platform for ISVs`

Comment: Record types are also unsupported.

Comment: This answer isn't fully correct (anymore). Permission Sets are supported, but they cannot be edited. This feature exists so that professional edition orgs with record types/custom profiles can assign custom permissions. API can be used in PE with a client ID (for ISV partners), even if the org isn't enabled for it. Same thing for canvas apps and connected apps.

Answer (score 3):

It is very important to note that when a feature is listed as "Not Supported" in GE/PE, this means ***there can be NO API references to the feature throughout your Code***. For instance, here are some gotchas related to non-supported features in GE/PE:

1. Record Types: just because your package does not include any Record Types on Standard or Custom Objects does not mean that your package can go in GE/PE. If your Package ever even **refers** to the `RecordType` API object, such as in a Utility method that you might use for your EE/UE customers for getting all active/available record types by name/id, your package will be excluded from GE/PE orgs. **However**, use of the DescribeSObjectResult `getRecordTypeInfos()` family of methods does *not* exclude your package from GE/PE. So in summary:

   - use of `Schema.RecordTypeInfo` IS allowed
   - use of `RecordType` object is NOT allowed.
2. Force.com Sites: again, any hard-coded reference to the `Site` or `SiteDomain` objects in Apex will exclude your package from GE/PE orgs. However, Dynamic SOQL, i.e. `Database.query('select Id from Site limit 1')` is a good way to get around this, ***as it moves the feature detection from compile-time to run-time***. I would assume that, as with `RecordTypeInfo`, use of the `System.Site` Apex class methods would *not* exclude you from GE/PE.

Furthermore, you might think that deprecating a method or part of your code that uses a not-allowed API object would allow successive versions to be allowed in GE/PE. Nope!

Also, a couple of features not supported in either GE or PE orgs not mentioned in Jordan's answer:

- Record Types
- Custom Report Types