# Sending an apex class from a dev account to a professional edition account

Tags: apex, professional-edition

So right now, I have made a package which contains a class that is needed to make a visualforce page on a professional edition account work.

What is the best step to send get that class over to the professional edition account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put custom Apex code directly into a Professional edition org. Typically this level of customization requires at least an Enterprise Edition Org.

See [Salesforce Features and Edition Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US).

The only way to get Apex code to run in a Professional edition org it via publishing to the App Exchange after passing the security review.

The question [Building an App that works in Group & Professional Edition?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/547/102) has some other good points about targeting a professional edition org.

Comment: Could you not use a private listing? Would that still require a security review?

Comment: @Girbot My understanding is that private apps haven't passed the security review yet. Hence they can't use Apex in a professional edition org. See [What does it mean when an AppExchange app is listed as private?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004523&language=en_US)